# showing error Insecure dependency in parameter 3 of DBI::db=HASH(0xa32bd40)->do method call while running with -T switch

Tags: perl, taint

i got the error Insecure dependency in parameter 3 of DBI::db=HASH(0xa32bd40)->do method call while running with -T switch while i modified the file show_bug.cgi

what is the reason?

Comment: could any one pls answer this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To untaint a variable, you must match it against a capturing regular expression. See [perlsec - Perl Security](http://p3rl.org/perlsec) for details.

Comment: what can be regular expression for strings?

Comment: @Jenifer_justin: You probably added a new parameter to a function. You should check that the value of the parameter is valid, e.g. if it is a number, use `$number =~ /^([0-9]+)$/`.

Comment: k. can i use the expression /^([-\@\w.]+)$/ for strings?

Comment: @Jenifer_justin: It really depends on what you expect in the new parameter.

Answer (score 3):

To untaint ie. variable `$unsecure`, a regular expression should be applied

```
my ($secure) = $unsecure =~ / (\d+) /x
  or die q{we couldn't find number in $unsecure};
```